# Has my book an errata or is my calculus wrong when differentiating $x^{2} = 2y^{2}\log{y}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In "Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes" there is a calculus problem at the very beggining that ask you to verify that:

If $x^{2} = 2y^{2}\log{y}$ then $y' = xy/x^{2} + y^{2}$

My differentiation is as follows:

$$
x^{2} = 2y^{2}\log{y}\\
2x = 4yy'\log{y} + 2y^{2}\frac{y'}{y} \\
2x = y' (4y\log{y} + 2y^{2}\frac{1}{y}) \\
y' = \frac{2x}{4y\log{y} + 2y} = \frac{x}{2y\log{y}+y} \\
y' = \frac{x}{2y\log{y}+y}\frac{y}{y} = \frac{xy}{2y^{2}\log{y}+y^{2}} \\
y' = \frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \neq xy/x^{2} + y^{2}
$$

Clould it be an errata? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a misprint, parentheses are missing.

Comment: It would make no sense for the author to intend to write $xy/x^2+y^2$ since that can be simplified to $y/x+y^2$.

Comment: I didn't thought about that, thank you @CarlaCvekla